# Navigation Bar and Search Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios9, uisearchbar

I want my navbar and search bar to be the same color. I also want to get rid of the hairline between them but that seems a minor issue compared to the first one.
The navbar attributes are set this way:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = ColorHelper.sharedInstance.LightPink()
    if let navBarFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 25.0) {
        let navBarAttributesDictionary: [String: AnyObject]? = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName: navBarFont
        ]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
 }
```

The search bar attributes:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for new friends"
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = ColorHelper.sharedInstance.LightPink()
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = ColorHelper.sharedInstance.LightPink()
searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

[image: The result]

It may seem as my `ColorHelper` returns different values for `LightPink` but it doesn´t. I've checked the color HEX-values and it's the navbar that is showing the color improperly, a bit lighter than it actually is. Any ideas why? Altering `.barStyle` did not change anything.

Comment: I've updated my answer below, there is answers for both your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Same color:**

I had the same problem and I solved it by setting `backroundImage` for my `UISearchBar` (1x1 pixel image with the same color as my `UINavigationBar`). And pay attention to `transluent` field – it must have the same value as your `UINavigationBar`

**Separator:**

To remove separator between navigation and search bar you can use this code in your `AppDelegate`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

But it works only if you set `transluent` field to false

Comment: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()` solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a Translucent in your NavBar. You should off the Transculent with this code, you can use in your viewDidLoad method.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

Also you can toggle translucent in the interface builder. Select your Navigation Controller then in the Document Outline select the Navigation Bar and just change it in the **Attributes Inspector** Uncheck the Translucent option.

If you don't want to disappear your navigationBar when user tap the your SearchBar use this;

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: The soultion worked for the view seen in the picture in my original post, they are now the same color. The problem is that when I select the search bar, the navbar used for searching is invisible. Any suggestions how to solve that?