# Translucent status bar overlapping UITableView content

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

So, my search bar looks like this and it is invoked via a `UISearchController`. It's all working fine except for one thing. 
[image: Find friends]

Scrolling down the search list will show the results under the status bar as it is transparent, like this

[image: ...]

I've used a couple of "ugly" fixes to get this looking and working as it and the problem clearly lies within the `translucent = true` - parameter. Can anyone see a quick solution to my problem? Other than jsut putting another empty, non-transparent view on top and make it white ofc. I've had another issue earlier today and the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384135/navigation-bar-and-search-controller/36384315?noredirect=1#comment60387783_36384315) problem is the reason why this happens..

```
func willPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    if let navBarFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 25.0) {
        let navBarAttributesDictionary: [String: AnyObject]? = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: PinkColor,
            NSFontAttributeName: navBarFont
        ]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Find Friends"
    self.refreshControl?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.refreshControl?.tintColor = self.GrayColor
}
func willDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    if let navBarFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 25.0) {
        let navBarAttributesDictionary: [String: AnyObject]? = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName: navBarFont
        ]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = self.PinkColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.PinkColor
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = self.PinkColor
        self.refreshControl?.backgroundColor = self.PinkColor
        self.refreshControl?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Friends"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```